# Check the file is existing in the folder or not in sdcard in Android

Tags: android, performance, android-download-manager

I am building an Android application which requires a empty database to be in specific folder of sdcard. Hence I build a code as download the database from the server and insert in the sdcard programmatically which is working fine. Now the issue is when I run the application from system, for every time new database is taking by replacing old database. Now I would like to change code as if database file not exists in the folder then only I need to download and save in specific folder

My code is here:

```
     String DownloadUrl = "http://myexample.com/android/timeexample.db";
     String fileName = "timeexample.db";

     DownloadDatabase(DownloadUrl,fileName);

public void DownloadDatabase(String DownloadUrl, String fileName) {
    try {
        File root = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File dir = new File(root.getAbsolutePath() + "/timeexample/databases");
        if(dir.exists() == false){
             dir.mkdirs();  
        }
        URL url = new URL("http://myexample.com/android/timeexample.db");
        File file = new File(dir,fileName);

        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Log.d("DownloadManager" , "download beginning");
        Log.d("DownloadManager" , "download url:" +url);
        Log.d("DownloadManager" , "download file name:" + fileName);

        URLConnection uconn = url.openConnection();
        uconn.setReadTimeout(TIMEOUT_CONNECTION);
        uconn.setConnectTimeout(TIMEOUT_SOCKET);

        InputStream is = uconn.getInputStream();

        BufferedInputStream bufferinstream = new BufferedInputStream(is);
        ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(5000);
        int current = 0;
        while((current = bufferinstream.read()) != -1){
            baf.append((byte) current);
        }
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream( file);
        fos.write(baf.toByteArray());
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
        Log.d("DownloadManager" , "download ready in" + ((System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime)/1000) + "sec");

    }

    catch(IOException e) {
        Log.d("DownloadManager" , "Error:" + e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
}
```

If every time I run like this, my data is missing as empty database is taking. hence my requirement is if database already exists, then no need to download. I have referred to many examples to overcome the issue.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
File extStore = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File myFile = new File(extStore.getAbsolutePath() + "/book1/page2.db");

if(myFile.exists()){
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to return from function when directory already exists

Here is your code

```
public void DownloadDatabase(String DownloadUrl, String fileName) {
try {
    File root = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File dir = new File(root.getAbsolutePath() + "/timeexample/databases");
    if(dir.exists() == false){
         dir.mkdirs();  
    }

URL url = new URL("http://myexample.com/android/timeexample.db");
    File file = new File(dir,fileName);
```

You Need to change it to

```
public void DownloadDatabase(String DownloadUrl, String fileName) {
try {
    File root = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File dir = new File(root.getAbsolutePath() + "/timeexample/databases");
    if(dir.exists() == false){
         dir.mkdirs();  
    }
    else 
      return 

URL url = new URL("http://myexample.com/android/timeexample.db");
    File file = new File(dir,fileName);
```

Answer (score 0):

for check database file exist or not use

```
File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/timeexample/databases/timeexample.db");
   if(f.exists())
   { 
     /* do whatever you want */ 
   }
```

now days there is two type of storage available in android device for that i ll sagest you to use

```
boolean mExternalStorageAvailable = false;
boolean mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();

if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
    // We can read and write the media
    mExternalStorageAvailable = mExternalStorageWriteable = true;
} else if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) {
    // We can only read the media
    mExternalStorageAvailable = true;
    mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
} else {
    // Something else is wrong. It may be one of many other states, but all we need
    //  to know is we can neither read nor write
    mExternalStorageAvailable = mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
}
```